# WordPress Plugin Boilerplate - add actions and/or filters based on user's role

Tags: plugin-development, filters, hooks, actions

I am developing a plugin using WordPress Plugin Boilerplate.

Some of its functionality need to be available only when a shortcode gets resolved in a page and furthermore some of it only if a user is logged in and has certain roles.

Inside enqueue_scripts() I am enqueueing my scripts, but I register those in the function fired by the shortcode; I also register some of them only for logged users with specific roles.
I do the same with css (using enqueue_styles()).

I am adding actions and filters inside define_public_hooks().

A bunch of those are there to associate ajax calls to their callback function, with all but one only necessary if the user is logged in and has certain roles.

Inside the ajax callbacks I do check for is_user_logged_in() and if so, for its roles.

Since is_user_logged_in() is not available inside define_public_hooks(): is there a way to avoid the overhead(? if any) and risks(? if any) of registering actions that are unnecessary unless user is logged in?

Comment: The logic for determining whether something should happen based on the user role should happen inside the callback function, not at the point of hooking the action.

Comment: thank you for the reply @JacobPeattie . I do that. I edited my question to give more details and context, I apologize for being too generic at first.